# Calling a function from controller1 within controller2 in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that updates my awards scope:

**Controller 1**

```
.controller("awardController", ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'Restangular', "$q", "$location", "TokenRestangular",
    function ($scope, $rootScope, Restangular, $q, $location, TokenRestangular) {


        $scope.updateAwardScope = function () {
            resource = TokenRestangular.all('award');
            resource.getList()
                .then(function (awards) {
                    $scope.awards = awards;

                })
        }

    }])
```

**Controller 2**

I have another controller 2 with a click event thats outside of this controllers scope. Is it possible for the controller below to call the `$scope.updateAwardScope` function from controller 1?

```
.controller('MainController', function ($rootScope, $scope) {

 $scope.updateAwardScopeClick = function () {
    // somehow call function from controller 1 

  }


});
```

Comment: Please use factory for that.

Comment: @micronyks thanks for the reply. I've used a factory for passing variables around, but how can I use one for calling a function?

Comment: Besides a factory you can also put the function inside a parent/$rootScope controller.  All child controllers will be able to use it.

Comment: "I've used a factory for passing variables around" - In javascript, functions can be variables. `var my_function = function() { } `;  So just do it the same way.

Comment: @dave thats interesting, do you have to evaluate it somehow so it knows its a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the use of the factory/service pattern to be a very effective way of reusing code in angular applications. For this particular case you could create an AwardFactory, inject it in your controllers and then call the update function. i.e

**AwardFactory**

```
myApp.factory('AwardFactory', ['TokenRestangular', function(TokenRestangular.all) {
  var factory = {
    awards: []
  };

  factory.update = function() {
    resource = TokenRestangular.all('award');

    resource.getList().then(function (awards) {
      factory.awards = awards;
    });

    return factory.awards; // You can skip the return if you'd like that
  };

  return factory;
}]);
```

**YourController**

```
.controller('MainController', function ($rootScope, $scope, AwardFactory) {

 $scope.updateAwardScopeClick = function () { 
   AwardFactory.update();
 }
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular broadcast and receive

Controller1

```
    .controller("awardController", ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'Restangular', "$q", "$location", "TokenRestangular",
function ($scope, $rootScope, Restangular, $q, $location, TokenRestangular) {


    $scope.updateAwardScope = function () {
        resource = TokenRestangular.all('award');
        resource.getList()
            .then(function (awards) {
                $scope.awards = awards;
                $rootScope.broadcast("update.awards");

            })
    }

}])
```

Controller 2

```
    .controller('MainController', function ($rootScope, $scope) {

     $rootScope.$on('update.awards', function(){
        $scope.updateAwardScopeClick();
     });

       $scope.updateAwardScopeClick = function () {
         // somehow call function from controller 1 

         }
       });
```